# Python Pillow / Numpy array are these pixels 'connected'?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

[image]

Given the image above I need to determine that RED is 'connected' to YELLOW (due to the green line), BLUE and PURPLE are not connected to anything.

Currently, I am doing something like:

- Generate coords for (straight) line between RED and YELLOW
- Check those coords for existence of GREEN pixels
- Score number of matched GREEN pixels and threshold the number of 'matches' to identify possible 'connected'.

This is obviously not that reliable in instances where there is a strong curve in the connecting line.

I already have an array that holds only the coords of green pixels(only) to try and 'walk' the green line from RED using KDtree queries for neighboring pixels etc. but I am not getting very far with this. Is there a function of numpy etc that would allow me to do this quickly, as I believe this array would hold the path of adjacent coords (from RED to YELLOW) should they exist.

Comment: Take a look at the flood fill algorithm

Comment: Not super efficient, but you can fill green pixels until you hit another color or run out.

Comment: Are you obliged to work with JPEG - which is nearly always a poor choice for intermediate files in image processing since it does not save pixels as you calculate them? Could you do yourself a favour and work in PNG?